# Comments Module {screen_name} -> {name} updating for previous comments?

Tags: comments, comment-form, screen-name

Version is EE2.11.3.

I have a private, members only blog with comments set up.

When submitting comments, the {name} input field doesn't seem to do anything. The comments module always defaults to the member's {screen_name}.

If a member changes their {screen_name} using the CP, default member templates, or template tags provided by Zeal Smart Members any past comments still keep the OLD {name} value.

NEW comments DO store the updated screen_name as name.

Looking through the comments table, the name column isn't getting updated. I would have thought it would, unless I have something set wrong?

Looks like DevDemon Freemember posted a fix for their module a few years ago to address something like this:

https://github.com/devdemon/freemember/pull/77/commits/3917d3037919bebd80163140635caa6c5f90001c

Does anyone here know how to get EE to properly update the comments "name" field when a member updates their "screen_name"?

Thank you,

```
{exp:comment:form
  channel="CHANNEL"
  entry_id="ENTRY_ID"
  return="{segment_1}/{segment_2}/updated"}

<input type="text" name="name" value="new_name"> <!-- doesn't do anything for logged in members -->
<input type="text" name="author" value="new_name"> <!-- worth a try but nothing -->
<input type="text" name="screen_name" value="new_name"> <!-- nope -->
<input type="checkbox" name="save_info" value="yes" {save_info} /> <!-- seems to just save a session cookie -->
<textarea name="comment"></textarea>

{/exp:comment:form}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am developer of [zeal smart members](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zeal-smart-members). To solve your problem, Please Open file: `system > ExpressionEngine > third_party > smart_members > libraries > sm_lib.php`

Search for this function: `function update_static_fields($member_id, $post_data)`

Change the code from:

```
if(isset($custom_data))
{
    $this->EE->member_model->update_member($member_id, $custom_data);
}
```

To

```
if(isset($custom_data))
{

    /*Special edit for comment module*/
    if(isset($custom_data['screen_name']))
    {

        $this->EE->db->select('module_name');
        $this->EE->db->where('module_name', 'Comment');
        $query = $this->EE->db->get('modules');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $this->EE->db->where('author_id', $member_id);
            $this->EE->db->update(
                'comments', 
                array('name' => $custom_data['screen_name'])
            );
        }

    }

    $this->EE->member_model->update_member($member_id, $custom_data);
}
```

Thanks for notify this, I will change the code of devote:ee with the updated fix.

Comment: I'm not familiar with zeal smart members but it's so great to see this level of support and rapid response time!

Comment: @AllInOne I agree, it is very nice to see. Mr. Mufaddal just saved me from hacking together a solution over the better part of a Saturday. I've been struggling with a upgrade path for EE2 > EE3. I have several ecommerce sites with dependencies that are still not ready. At this pace, EE4 will be announced by the time I make the jump. So far the Zeal Smart Members module has been a smooth and welcome experience.

Comment: Thank you @Mufaddal Nala. I can confirm that your update is working. I'll test a few more scenarios and then return to mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Thank you to "AllInOne" and "oliverb". I am happy our product help you in development. For any of our product, you can ask support here or devote:ee forum.